# Statemachine core 4.0.0 ( Executing eventNotAccepted method)

Tags: spring-statemachine

We upgraded spring core to 4.0.0 version. As per our implementation we have extended  `StateMachineListenerAdapter<S, E>` and overridden eventNotAccepted method like below:

```
@Override
public void eventNotAccepted(Message<E> event) {
    logger.warn(log, "eventNotAccepted", LogMessage.EVENT_NOT_ACCEPTED , event.getPayload());
}
```

We observed, on every event we are getting above warning message, that means eventNotAccepted method is executing by the statemachine framework.  But, there is no issue state transition for any event even though eventNotAccepted warning.

In older version 2.2.0 we had this method, but this method never executed.
Is it a bug in statemachine 4.0.0 or do we need to handle some other way?

We debugged a lot but did not find any clue.

Comment: Request to `spring-statemachine` team , could you please suggest something, we need some assistance urgently. Please look into it and give some direction.